# Drawing lines in a view getting cleared iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, drawing

I am drawing in a uiview by subclassing a uiview and drawing code is in the

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

method.
I am repeatedly calling this to get a growing effect for a line. But every time the method calls the view get cleared. Only small line ig ploted in the view
my complete code is

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    static int i=0;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);       
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10.0);        
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, i, i);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, i+10, i+10);  
    NSLog(@"-----%d",i);    
    CGContextClosePath(context);            
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke); 
    i++;
    if(i<100)
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.033];
}
```

How can I make a growing effect for line

Answer (score 1):

In this case you redraw all your view, so you need to use `CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);`. So every time you perform all drawing.
Also you can call `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` to redraw only a small part, but in this case you should examine what rect you get to perform all drawing when all view is redrawn.

Comment: setNeedsDisplayInRect: passes CGRect as its argument how can I pass a structure in 
[self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.033];
method. I think it only takes an object

Comment: You can use your own selector `drawAnotherPiseceOfLine` with only one line of code `setNeedsDisplayInRect:...`, also in this case your `i` should be ivar, or class varible, not in method `drawRect:` defined.

Answer (score 0):

DrawRect draws **ALL** of your UI every time it is called, not an additional part to the already existing parts - so in fact at the moment you are drawing one single line every time. You have to draw a rectangle with growing size on every iteration to achieve the effect you want.